# Integrate multiple layout with ember rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-rails

My Rails App has multiple layouts, which correspond to different controller.

How could I integrate it with ember rails ?

I have no idea.Please give me some direction, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Ember before ?

Comment: I would suggest Learn directly Ember and design something, then build JSON API using Rails and finally make your front-end (Ember) talk to the API, if you want some practice you can go through this tutorial https://devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux-part-1-the-api-and-cms-with-ruby-on-rails . I think this is probably the simplest way you can develop Rails-Ember App.

Comment: Have you looked at ember-cli-rails? 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails

You can define where you want your ember app to render inside of a rails template, allowing you to use multiple layouts from rails.